# How bad could be 'Overriding managed version 2.8.1 for gson' warning at spring-boot? How could it be avoided?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gson

I'm using spring-boot at my parent project. Inside a child project, I intend to use Gson library. When I added it on child project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I got this warning:

```
Overriding managed version 2.8.1 for gson
```

After removing `<version>`, I got this warning:

```
The managed version is 2.8.1 The artifact is managed in org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.7.RELEASE
```

Since it's already present at spring-boot, why after I remove the dependency from `pom` I can't import `Gson` to my classes? How should I do to use this library along with spring-boot?

**EDIT**

I tried to

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

at my `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, `spring-boot-starter-logging`, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-cache` (all my spring-boot dependencies) but it didn't work.

Using original `dependency` tag I successfully managed to use this dependency at Java, but my question is how bad it is to ignore this warning? What could go wrong using different Gson version dependencies?

Comment: try with 2.8.0 version as its already managed by Spring  dependencies
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.5.7.RELEASE

Comment: update dependencies while building using --update-dependencies flag

Comment: @Amit same warning: `Overriding managed version 2.8.1 for gson`

Comment: @piy26 I assume you are referring to -U flag, which force to update dependencies? If so, it didn't work. If you're referring to other flag, please could you be more specific? `--update-dependencies` doesn't exist as a mvn flag

Comment: I referred to same -U flag